# Html Divs aren't responsive

Tags: css, html, asp.net-mvc-5, responsive-design

```html
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row">


            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



                <div class="col-md-6 active" id="main-content" style="border: 0.5px solid rgba(4,4,4,.4)  ;box-shadow: 5px  5px 5px #99ccff;  border-radius: 5px; margin-right:10px;float:left;width: 58%; height:40%;margin-left:-10%;">



                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <h3 style="text-align:center; border-radius:5px;margin:5px;padding:15px;color:black">Title</h3>
                        <hr />
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4 " })


                            <div class="col-md-6">

                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })


                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div>
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailConfirmed, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailConfirmed)
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailConfirmed, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>





                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PasswordHash, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PasswordHash, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordHash, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SecurityStamp, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SecurityStamp, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SecurityStamp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumberConfirmed, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumberConfirmed, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>




                    </div>

                </div>








                <div class="col-md-6 active" id="sidebar-right" style="border: 0.5px solid  rgba(4,4,4,.4);
    box-shadow: 5px  5px 5px  #99ccff;border-radius: 5px; margin-bottom:11%;float:right   ; margin-right:-10%; width: 58%; height:200px ;margin-left:1%; position:relative;">




                    <h3 style="text-align:center; border-radius:5px;margin:5px;padding:15px;color:black">Title</h3>

                    <hr />


                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TwoFactorEnabled, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TwoFactorEnabled)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TwoFactorEnabled, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LockoutEndDateUtc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LockoutEndDateUtc, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LockoutEndDateUtc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>






















                <div class="col-md-6 active" style="border: 0.5px solid  rgba(4,4,4,.4);
    box-shadow: 5px  5px 5px  #99ccff;border-radius: 5px; margin-top:-20%;float:right ;margin-right:-10%; width: 58%; height:100%;margin-left:5%; position:relative;">

                    <h3 style="text-align:center; border-radius:5px;margin:5px;padding:15px; color:black">Title</h3>
                    <hr />


                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LockoutEnabled, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LockoutEnabled)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LockoutEnabled, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccessFailedCount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccessFailedCount, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccessFailedCount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                            &nbsp;
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="btn-toolbar" style="float:left;">
                    <br />
                    <input type="reset" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" />



                    <button type="button" class="btn">Basic</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>

                </div>
















            }




        </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

So , im working on this view , and i am newby to css/html . The problem here is that these divs arent responsive , so when i change the browser width , these divs stays in fixed position and not go responsive one under another .i would appriciate every help.So , im working on this view , and i am newby to css/html . The problem here is that these divs arent responsive , so when i change the browser width , these divs stays in fixed position and not go responsive one under another .i would appriciate every help.

```html
 <div style="display:block">


        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



            <div class="col-md-6 active" style="border: 0.5px solid  ;box-shadow: 5px  5px 5px #99ccff;  border-radius: 5px;margin-right:10px;float:left;width: 55%; height:40%;margin-left:-10%;">



                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <h3 style="text-align:center; border-radius:5px;margin:5px;padding:15px;color:black">Title</h3>
                    <hr />
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4 " })


                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })


                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailConfirmed, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailConfirmed)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailConfirmed, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>





                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PasswordHash, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PasswordHash, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordHash, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SecurityStamp, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SecurityStamp, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SecurityStamp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumberConfirmed, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumberConfirmed, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>




                </div>

            </div>








            <div class="col-md-6 active" style="border: 0.5px solid  ;
    box-shadow: 5px  5px 5px  #99ccff;border-radius: 5px; margin-bottom:10%;float:right ;margin-right:-5%; width: 55%; height:1
    00%;margin-left:1%; position:relative;">




                <h3 style="text-align:center; border-radius:5px;margin:5px;padding:15px;color:black">Title</h3>

                <hr />


                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TwoFactorEnabled, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TwoFactorEnabled)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TwoFactorEnabled, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LockoutEndDateUtc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LockoutEndDateUtc, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LockoutEndDateUtc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>






















            <div class="col-md-6 active" style="border: 0.5px solid  ;
    box-shadow: 5px  5px 5px  #99ccff;border-radius: 5px; margin-top:-20%;float:right ;margin-right:-5%; width: 55%; height:100%;margin-left:5%; position:relative;">

                <h3 style="text-align:center; border-radius:5px;margin:5px;padding:15px; color:black">Title</h3>
                <hr />


                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LockoutEnabled, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LockoutEnabled)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LockoutEnabled, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccessFailedCount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccessFailedCount, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccessFailedCount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                        &nbsp;
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="btn-toolbar" style="float:left;">
                <br />
                <input type="reset" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" />



                <button type="button" class="btn">Basic</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>

            </div>
















        }




    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Set the width/height using a % value, such as 50% and you will see them re-size with the browser.

Comment: I did but still the same

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using bootstrap you should have your columns contained within a `.row`, which should be contained within a `.container`.    The container will then resize depending on viewport and the columns will size as a % of the container.

E.g

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">Col 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Col 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More info here:  [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)

Comment: I did not give u downvote ,its my first day here , i still dont know how to use this whole interface ..nevermind ! i added container and row classes but still the same , please check the edit post below.

Comment: You need to specify different `col-*` classes to specify how you want things to size on different display sizes.   E.G.   `.col-md-6`  would be 50% wide on medium screens, but will change to 100% width on smaller screens if no `.col-sm-*` or `.col-xs-*` classes are specified.    Can you post your modified code?.

Comment: I understand this , but its not first time i use bootstrap with CRUD in ASP.NET MVC . It should resize when i adjust the browser width , but all it does is divs go One Over Another.

Comment: The code shown in your original post doesn't have the correct `.container` and `.row` divs, so this won't be responsive.    Please try the example given above, or read the Bootstrap documentation